# Use Google Sheets as a small database - vLookup and duplicates issue

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

While I am aware that Google Sheets is not a database, I am attempting to use data in a master->child fashion

Let's say we have a Google Sheet used as a data validation "table"

```
********************************
ID     | Name | Place of Birth
********************************
1      | Mike | London
2      | Sue  | Paris
3      | Bob  | San Francisco
4      | Mike | Brasilia
```

Now, we want to use this table as a data validation range in another sheet, while storing the related ID, once the selection has been made.

Let's use a spreadsheet containing two sheets [here's the link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fLCq_zbsS5DSn6cihsfo3z-ywBiEzgb7PSZnwj7UtHE/edit#gid=0):

- `Data Validation` sheet, which holds lookup values
- `a generic sheet` which uses the Data Validation sheet as a range for data validation. Column A (hidden) will hold numeric IDs, depending on the value selected from the lookup table

  `=arrayformula( iferror( vlookup(B2:B, { 'Data Validation table'!B2:B, 'Data Validation table'!A2:A }, 2, false) ) )`

However in case of duplicates, this trick will fail. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: First you have to decide which result do you want in case of duplicate? Suppose you select `Mike` then which ID do you want to return in column A?

Comment: There should be a way to differentiate, how data is shown in the dropdown menu

Comment: I believe this is what you're asking for without knowing that you're asking for it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-I8Z4nTDak

Comment: Nice, but how would this help in the above problem?